# Using part of input as a filename

Tags: python, file, input, command

I'm working on a program that takes a list and manages them as lists and tuples.

I have a rather embarrassingly simple (or so it seems) question: If I have an input function for the command for the main loop, how do I write an if/elif/else etc using the command plus a filename in the same input?

Example:

Commands available: QUIT, INPUT filename

```
    cmd = input("Please input a command: ")
    while cmd != "QUIT":
        if cmd == "INPUT filename"
            file = open("filename")
            for line in file:
                line_list = line.strip().split(";")
                main_list.append(line_list)
```

I don't know how to get it to recognize the filename part of the INPUT command as the filename to use, while also making it simple to have the IF statement be if cmd == "INPUT filename" or similar, if you know what I'm trying to say.

Comment: First, your indentation is wrong below the for loop.

Comment: Eh sorry, that was just due to never having written code on stack overflow before :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `filename` won't ever have spaces, you can use

```
filename = cmd.split(' ')[1]
```

Otherwise, you know the length of the first part of the command, so you can use:

```
filename = cmd[6:]
```

I think the second option is preferable. In your code, this would look like

```
cmd = input("Please input a command: ")
while cmd != "QUIT":
    if cmd.startswith("INPUT"): 
        if len(cmd) < 7:
            print "Usage: INPUT <filename>"
            continue
        filename = cmd[6:]
        file = open("filename")
        for line in file:
            line_list = line.strip().split(";")
            main_list.append(line_list)
```

If you have other commands, `INPUT` or `SAVE` etc, you could use something like

`argument = cmd[len(command_name):]`

Answer (score 1):

```
    cmd = input("Please input a command: ")
    while cmd != "QUIT":
        if cmd.startswith("INPUT"):
            cmd = cmd.split()
            if len(cmd) != 2:
                print "Usage: INPUT <filename>"
            else:
                file = open(cmd[1])
```